# Python lxml - get selected options

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to access selected options in select using `lxml` but looks like `lxml` doesn't know about this property. Here is my code:

```
for option in productField.xpath('select//option'):
    if 'selected' in option.attrib:
        print(option)
```

When I do `print(option.attrib)` I see only `{'value': 'value...'}`. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are you trying to view the value of the `selected` attribute? If so then you want `print(option.attrib['selected'])`

Comment: @iafisher, yes, it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
if (productField.xpath('select//option[@selected="selected"]')):
    for option in productField.xpath('select//option[@selected="selected"]'):
        print(option)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***selected*** option:

```
productField.xpath("//select/option[@selected='selected']/text()")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select = root.iter("select")
    for s in select:
        print(len(s))
        for e in s.getchildren():
            print(e.tag, e.attrib.get('value'), e.text, tree.getpath(e))
```